# Deactivate precompiled headers by default Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

Every time I create a new project, I deactivate the pre-compiled headers in going in Properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers. Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to not have precompiled headers every time I create a project so I don't have to do it each time manually?

Comment: This may be better asked on an MSDN website or forum.

Comment: I tend to check the box "Empty Project", in the Project creation wizard, when creating C++ projects. That way, there's no pregenerated fluff, including precompiled headers.